# Python: how to access a custom parameter on the RecycleView creation?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-recycleview

I would like to know where can I see and use the parameters given on the data during the creation of the widgets.

Problem: it looks like `__init__` doesn't have the information so the call has to be after so I would like to know when to be able to use my custom paramaters.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.factory import Factory as F

Builder.load_string('''
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'CustomLabel'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class CustomLabel(F.Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(kwargs, "why can't I see the stuff from data ???")

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x), "new_parameter":"idk where am I"} for x in range(100)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties from the `data` are not set in the `__init__()` method of the `CustomLabel`, they are each set individually after creating the basic `CustomLabel`. You can see this by adding an `on_text()` method to your `CustomLabel`:

```
class CustomLabel(F.Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(kwargs, "why can't I see the stuff from data ???")

    def on_text(self, instance, new_text):
        print('CustomLabel', id(instance), 'text set to:', new_text)
```

Comment: Can we access this event ? Can we be prevent when the data is added ? (and add some stuff then, I need to do use the stuff from data the moment I get the access)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A change to the `data` triggers a refresh of the `CustomLabels`. You can bind a method to `data` (or just add an `on_data()` method in the `RV` class), but  changing the `data`  in such a method will trigger another call to that method. Easy to create an infinite loop like that.

Comment: I have multiple `TextInput` in a "Row" (`BoxLayout`). My `RecycleView` is full of "Row". I give "text_list" as parameter in the data but I don't know how to write them in the launch. (I tried to write it on `__init__` and `on_kv_post` but that doesn't work. This is why I need to find the function I have to bind to (or overide). I know how to use the `refresh()` but it's already too late in the process line.

Comment: (I didn't want to afraid people with a complex example, this is why I simplified it but the purpose is more obscur, indeed :p)